# Pandas DataFrame column string concatenation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a column of strings like so:

```
      col1         
         a            
         b            
         c            
         d
```

I also have a string variable `x = 'x'` and a list of strings `list1 = ['ax', cx']`

I want to create a new column that checks if the concatenated string of `col1 + x` is in list1. If yes then col2 = 1 else col2 = 0.

Here is my attempt:

`df['col2'] = 1 if str(df['col1'] + x) in list1 else 0`

Which doesn't work.

`df['col2'] = 1 if df['col1'] + x in list1 else 0`

Doesn't work either.

What would be the correct way to format this?
Thank you for any help.

```
      col1         col2  <-- should be this
         a            1
         b            0
         c            1
         d            0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isin`:

```
df['col2'] = df.col1.add('x').isin(list1).astype(int)

#  col1  col2
#0    a     1
#1    b     0
#2    c     1
#3    d     0
```

[Check Results](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/50e3dcbc.py)

Comment: Both answers work perfectly. Will accept this because its slightly cleaner. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` function as follows.

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(lambda val: 1 if x + val in list1 else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

An other solution using `apply` :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','b','c', 'd']})

def func(row):
    list1 = {'ax', 'cx'}
    row['col2'] = 1 if row.col1 + 'x' in list1 else 0
    return row

df2 = df.apply(func, axis='columns')

# OUTPUTS : 
#  col1  col2
#0    a     1
#1    b     0
#2    c     1
#3    d     0
```